# How to Count Rows with Specific values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have like below formatted table rows. I need to count the rows based on status.

**E.g:**

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
|SNo | Operation | Status         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|1   |   OP10    | Complete       |
|1   |   OP10    | Complete       |
|2   |   OP10    | Complete       |
|2   |   OP10    | Complete       |
|2   |   OP10    | Complete       |
|3   |   OP20    | InProgress     |
|3   |   OP20    | InProgress     |
|3   |   OP20    | InProgress     |
|4   |   OP30    | Ready          |
|4   |   OP30    | Ready          |
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

Output:

```
Sno  Operation   CountStatus
----------------------------
1     OP10            2
2     OP10            3
3     OP20            3
4     OP30            0
```

I need to count if the status is 'Complete' & 'Inprogress'. IF the status is 'Ready' means need to show the count is '0'.

Comment: Did you try aggregate function with case statement ?

Comment: Do you not want `OP10` to show a `CountStatus` of 5? Or do you want the description of `Status` included in your results?

Comment: I want to show OP10 2 for Sno 1 & OP10 3 for sno2. I don't want to show OP10 for 5. Because Sno is different.

Answer (score 5):

Use conditional aggregation:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
Declare @T as table
(
    Sno int,
    Operation char(4),
    Status varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'OP10', 'Complete'),
(1, 'OP10', 'Complete'),
(2, 'OP10', 'Complete'),
(2, 'OP10', 'Complete'),
(2, 'OP10', 'Complete'),
(3, 'OP20', 'InProgress'),
(3, 'OP20', 'InProgress'),
(3, 'OP20', 'InProgress'),
(4, 'OP30', 'Ready'),
(4, 'OP30', 'Ready')
```

The query:

```
SELECT Sno, 
       Operation, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status IN('Complete', 'Inprogress') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As CountStatus
FROM @T
GROUP BY Sno, Operation
ORDER BY Sno
```

Results:

```
Sno Operation   CountStatus
1   OP10        2
2   OP10        3
3   OP20        3
4   OP30        0
```

Comment: It's working but I want to show OP10 2 for Sno 1 & OP10 3 for sno2. I don't want to show OP10 for 5. Because Sno is different.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise this would be better

```
Select t.sno,t.operation, tt.cno
from (select distinct t.sno, t.operation from tablename t) t 
inner join (select t.sno, 
cno = count(case when Status in ('Complete', 'InProgress') then 1 else null end)  
                    from tablename group by sno)tt on t.sno = tt.sno
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used simple case statement

```
SELECT
        SNO,Operation,SUM(CASE Status WHEN 'Complete' THEN 1 
                                  WHEN 'InProgress' THEN 1
                                  WHEN 'Ready' THEN 0 END) AS Cnt_Status
FROM Your_table
GROUP BY SNO,Operation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

select SNo,operation, COUNT(sno) from table1
group by sno,operation